# Pull current year and next 2 years from a date field

Tags: sql

I have a date field that has years of dates (formatted `mm/dd/yyyy`). What I'm trying to do is to only pull dates of current year (starting from the Jan 1st) AND next 2 rolling years. So in total, I should have 730 days. I guess what I'm trying to do is to always have a rolling 2 years of dates starting from current year.

My current oracle sql Im using is the following but I dont know where to go from here or if its even wrong all together. Thanks in advance.

```
select date
from table1
where extract (year from date)>= extract(year from sysdate)
```

Comment: What is the data type of the column? Is it really a date, or is it a string column type like varchar that's only pretending to be a date?

Comment: you need to edit your question and 1) show the table DDL, 2) show sample data, 3) show expected output.

Comment: `where extract(year from date) - extract(year from sysdate) in (0, 1)` Not gonna be efficient though.